# An Index for an Enumerate Document

Tags: pdftex, page-numbering, indexing, imakeidx, makeindex

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{idxlayout}

\newtcbox{\blackbox}[1][]{nobeforeafter, notitle, %sharpcorners,
     colframe=yellow!20!black,
     colback=yellow!50!black,
     top=4pt,
     left=5pt,
     right=5pt,
     bottom=2pt,
     fontupper=\sffamily\bfseries,
     colupper=white,
     tcbox raise base,
     #1}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{label*={\blackbox{\arabic*}}}

\begin{document}
\Large
\begin{enumerate}
\item Contains stuff to be indexed by item number.\index{1st item index entry}
\item Contains more stuff to be similarly indexed.\index{2nd item index entry}
\item And lots more stuff to be index the same way.\index{3rd item index entry}
\item etc.\index{4th item index entry}
\item etc. etc.\index{5th item index entry}
\item etc. etc. etc.\index{6th item index entry}
\end{enumerate}

\idxlayout{columns=2}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

which produces the following output on the first page:

[image]

Along with the index

[image]

QUESTION: How may I easily modify the code within `pdflatex` so that specific item numbers are delineated in the index instead of page numbers (which in this case is uniformily 1)?

Answer (score 1):

To do this requires some minor surgery on the `\index` command. First, we'll look up its definition (`texdoc source2e` and then go to **File P Index and Glossary Generation** (p. 743) to find the current definition:

```
\def\makeindex{%
  \newwrite\@indexfile
  \immediate\openout\@indexfile=\jobname.idx
  \def\index{% ❶
     \@bsphack % ❷
     \begingroup % ❸
     \@sanitize % ❸
     \@wrindex
  }%
  \typeout{Writing index file \jobname.idx}%
}

\def\@wrindex#1{%
   \protected@write\@indexfile{}%
      {\string\indexentry{#1}{\thepage}}% ❹
   \endgroup % ❸
   \@esphack % ❷
}
```

I've made some minor formatting changes for the sake of clarity.

Some things worth noting:

1. `\index` is (re)defined ❶ in the `\makeindex` command. The default definition, a little lower in the file turns `\index` into, essentially a no-op.
2. `\@bsphack`…`\@esphack` is a clever device used in LaTeX in a few different commands so that if you write something like:

   ```
   this
   \index{index entry}
   that
   ```

   you still get only one space in the output. It'll even correctly manage end-of-sentence spacing. However, it can sometimes cause bad output if you have a space at the end of a paragraph as a space that would otherwise be discarded will be retained and could cause a blank line to be output.
3. `\index` will treat any special characters in its input as non-special, which is why there's a group around everything and `\@sanitize` to change character codes and `\@wrindex` has to be a separate macro (otherwise the category codes would already be frozen when the argument is read). This fancy treatment does not, however, work, if `\index` appears in the argument to another command which can result in surprising duplicate index entries if you have, e.g., `\index{\d{o}}` appearing twice in your document, once in a footnote, once outside a footnote.¹

But, you say, I don't want a dissertation, I just want to change what gets indexed. Fair enough. What we'll need to do is modify the definition of `\@wrindex` to use the enumerate counter instead of the page number. For this we'll just change what goes in place of `\thepage` ❹.

Your first thought might be to just write

```
\makeatletter
\def\@wrindex#1{%
   \protected@write\@indexfile{}%
      {\string\indexentry{#1}{\theenumi}}%
   \endgroup
   \@esphack}
\makeatother
```

and declare victory, but what if you have nested enumerations and you want a reference to bar below to be 1(a)?

> 1. Foo
>
>    a. bar
>
>    b. baz
> 2. Bam

In this instance, we can instead write `\@currentlabel` in place of `\theenumi` which will cause the value written to be the most recent counter that can be referred to with `\label` and `\ref` (and enumerated items are in that list).

---

1. Can you tell I've been spending a lot of time doing indexing lately?

Comment: Thank you for posting this; however, when I incorporate the `\makeatletter` subroutine into the preamble, I get an error. If you wouldn't mind, It would be very helpful to incorporate your  suggestions into  the MWE and then post it and the answer for visual clarity.  Many thanks.

Comment: Also, is there a closing brace missing in your `\def\makeindex`? Thanks again.

Comment: There was a missing brace in the copied definition of `\makeindex`. I've fixed that. I don't get an error with copy and pasting the definition above into a clean document. It would be helpful if you could indicate exactly what the error you get is.

Comment: Perhaps I am assembling your pieces incorrectly. Would you be able to post your complete working code? Thank you.

Comment: +1: Nice code annotations. BTW, looking forward to your book! I participated in the Kickstarter campaign.